# When restarting application service, it is throwing an Error: 1061

Tags: .net, service

Application service is running on a service ID. Every time I restart the service it throws the error below:

> 1061 The services cannot accept control messages

I will have to manually kill the service through PowerShell using the kill command and again enter the service ID and Password manually for the service to run. It is happening on only a few servers in the same environment. Is this an application configuration issue or a Windows/IIS issue? Please advise.

I checked all the application configurations and restarted the Credential Manager service.